# Neo4J get node by ID

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j for one of my project, there's a node which only has a single property as `name`, I want to get that node using ID, it already has a ID but when I use this code

`MATCH (s:SKILLS{ID:65110}) return s`

It returns nothing, heres my node

[image]

If the query is wrong then how do I query it using the number

Comment: Which graph visualizing tool do you use ? Thanks. 
I know of https://www.yworks.com/neo4j-explorer good option for customization.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
MATCH (s)
WHERE ID(s) = 65110
RETURN s
```

The [`ID` function](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-id) gets you the id of a node or relationship. This is different from any property called `id` or `ID` that you create.

Comment: is there any different way to get data like (s:SomeLabel {id:65110}) ?

Comment: @DonkeyKong No, because you can also add the id property, which is something else than the id. An id property can have any type, while the node or edge id is an unsigned integer, linked to a location in the internal structure of Neo4J.

Comment: STANDARD DISCLAIMER: Don't use internal Neo4j IDs for long-term entity identification.  Future versions of Neo4j might shift these IDs around for performance purposes.  Create your own unique ID property (ideally with a `CONSTRAINT`) for tracking entities

Comment: Adding official cypher's documentation paragraph if someone interested: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#get-node-rel-by-id

Answer (score 21):

> [`START` should only be used when accessing legacy indexes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160215063618/http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-start.html). It is [disabled in Cypher <s>2.2</s> 3.2 and up](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108065403/https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/).
>
> Neo4j [recommends using `WHERE ID(n) =`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330234604/http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_get_node_or_relationship_by_id) , and furthermore states that it [will only require a single lookup (does not scan every node to find the matching ID)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611051524/http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans-starting-query.html#query-plan-node-by-id-seek)

| [image] WARNING |
| --- |
| The answer below is ***incorrect***. It is listed for reference only. See the updated answer above (quoted). The text below is kept for reference only |

You ***can*** use `WHERE ID(s) = 65110`, but this will check the ID of every node in your database.

There is a more efficient way to do this:

```
START s=NODE(517) MATCH(s) RETURN s
```

Comment: Results from EXPLAIN and PROFILE for a simple query showed me that @Code was right. Why is this not in the docs?

Comment: @Sonata What version are you running? Newer versions of Neo4j should make START obsolete.

Comment: 3.0.7. Have a look at the `Result Details` from these examples in the console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/dbz1we (doing an AllNodesScan) and http://console.neo4j.org/r/9076wd (doing a NodeById)

Comment: @Sonata I'm not sure why this is happening. First of all, it shouldn't work - docs state that START is deprecated as of Cypher 2.0 and disabled as of Cypher 2.2, but it's clearly still working. Second of all, MATCH with ID should be a [`+NodeByIdSeek` accessing only 1 node](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans-starting-query.html#query-plan-node-by-id-seek) but for some reason it is doing an `+AllNodesScan`.

Comment: all of the links are dead. Can you update them?

Comment: @Ooker thanks for letting me know. Please note I did not have any updated links and had to archived links from archive.org. Anyone is free to do the same and update an outdated answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can say:

```
(n:User) where id(n) >=20 RETURN n
```

this will return all nodes of type User with node reference ID more than 20

Answer (score 1):

Below cypher query gives you the solution:

```
MATCH (s:SKILLS) where n.ID contain '65110' return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer create ID property yourself.

Using system created ID is not advisable and should be avoided, for best practice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 5, the function [id()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) has been deprecated. To achieve the same result, you need to use new function [elementId](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id)

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE elementId(n) = $id
RETURN n.name
```