# Get node or relationship by ID in Neo4j embedded java

Tags: java, neo4j

I looked at how I can easily [get a Node by ID through cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369520/neo4j-get-node-by-id), yet the methods that are available for the Node interface do not appear to support a way to return a particular [Node](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.3/) object based on ID.

How can I return a particular node by ID with the Neo4j embedded Java library?  Same question with relationships...

Comment: Prefer this question be opened back up.  This is a very specific question within the Neo4J embedded Java framework.  Looking at the documents for the Node interface, I do not see a way to return a Node object based on ID.  That was my question.  This is either a very simple and specific answer or there is no straight forward way to do what is otherwise easy to do in Cypher (the neo4j query language)

Comment: It seems that almost all of the people who voted to close have never asked/answered a neo4j question. This question is indeed very focused.

Anway, the anwers are: you use [GraphDatabaseService.getNodeById](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getNodeById(long)) and [GraphDatabaseService.getRelationshipById](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getRelationshipById(long))

Comment: OMG thank you so much!  I hadn't come across that interface in the docs yet, didn't seem like the natural place for such a method.

Comment: Hopefully they open the question back up and you can answer and get points.  Agree, putting this on hold was a bit short-sighted and folks likely didn't realize that Nodes are a specific object type within the Neo4j framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [GraphDatabaseService.getNodeById](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getNodeById(long)) and [GraphDatabaseService.getRelationshipById](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getRelationshipById(long)).